# Trying to Upgrade froM MVC3 to MVC4, all ok bar one component which is still referencing 3.0.0.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, mvcsitemapprovider

I have upgraded my MVC3 application using the Nuget UpgradeFromMvc3ToMvc4 which has worked fine, except for one component. I did uninstall the V3 of this "MvcSiteMapProvider" component before upgrading, and then installed "MvcSiteMap Core V4" after the MVC4 upgrade.

Ther error I get is:

```
Error   41  Assembly 'MvcSiteMapProvider, Version=4.6.18.0,  
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1923abe4657913cc' uses 'System.Web.Mvc, 
Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which 
has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, 
Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'  
d:\..\MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC4.Core.4.6.18\lib\net45   
\MvcSiteMapProvider.dll
```

There is no reference to 3.0.0.0 in my solution. I have done a "find" in "all files". So am confused.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: try drop refference and add again - sometimes it helps.

Comment: Reference to MvcSiteMap?

Comment: Yeap. In witch Dll it's situated?

Comment: Just tried it. Did not work. . The one in my nuget package, and the one I tried to re-reference is MvcSiteMapProvider.dll

Comment: Where do you think it is getting "which 
has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, 
Version=3.0.0.0"

Comment: From System.Web.Mvc dll =) Try frop this base refference and i hope it will help you

Comment: Just done this and re-added system.web.mvc 4.0.0.1 and it seems to have done the trick. Please put it as an answer and I will mark up. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop refference to `System.Web.MVC` and readd it.
Sometimes this just happends.